# How to navigate one app component to another app component in angular4?

Tags: angular, routes

My requirement is:- If there are two apps. app1 and app2. app1 some components and similarly app2. So how to redirect on click app1 component click to app2 component.

Please tell me.

Comment: Refer to the docs for [**angular routing**](https://angular.io/guide/router)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your routing module be like..

```
imports goes here ....;

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: HomePageComponent,
  },
  {
    path: "newPage",
    component: NewPageComponent,
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

And, let your default url be localhost:4200, then, on url, localhost:4200/newPage you will see the new component loaded i.e. `NewPageComponent` mentioned in `Routes`.